# Is it possible to set a range of magnitude for each row in a heatmap pyqtgraph?

Tags: pyqt5, heatmap, pyqtgraph

I'm working with pyqtgraph trying to reproduce a heatmap like this one:

[image]

I've checked the documentation, wrote a simple code and got this result:

[image]

Far from what I was expecting. Both image is plotting the same data.

Here a minimum reproducible example (I had to trim the data for this example!) :

```
import pandas as pd
import pyqtgraph as pg
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from pyqtgraph.Qt import mkQApp


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        gr_win = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget(show=True)
        self.setCentralWidget(gr_win)
        self.show()

        vals = [[1159827.25, 2037752.875, 1707160.875, 246714.2188, 296667.125 ],
                [1169353.625, 2040003.5, 1658506.625, 239984.8906, 296498.2188],
                [1171017.625, 2011996.5, 1656728.875, 237053.7813, 293604.875],
                [1178574.375, 2072736, 1663694.25, 235140.8906, 299649.3438],
                [1159688, 2083889.75, 1643331.5, 234067.5625, 304685.3438],
                [1152916.75, 2053664, 1679658.625, 238763.5625, 300437.7813],
                [1150568, 2009809.75, 1670744.875, 231581.3281, 301518.6563],
                [ 4027998, 17364368, 3405127.5, 261904.8906, 293540.875],
                [1.33838312e+08, 1.68094592e+08, 6.62438640e+07, 1.03730562e+06, 3.84640875e+05],
                [1.14740528e+08, 1.86216192e+08, 6.06729000e+07, 9.69294375e+05, 3.82200875e+05],
                [1.03464440e+08, 1.48697360e+08, 4.80718720e+07, 8.12308812e+05, 3.71445344e+05],
                [1.02383888e+08, 1.15441008e+08, 4.85811120e+07, 8.26331188e+05, 3.65720000e+05],
                [9.00053360e+07, 1.26687472e+08, 3.87457280e+07, 7.18004812e+05, 3.54461781e+05],
                [8.16222880e+07, 1.04054032e+08, 3.81338880e+07, 7.12791188e+05, 3.43088438e+05],
                [72061952, 80340944, 33945716, 638232.8125, 341960],
                [65119580, 70061216, 32259310, 649017.625, 350463.125],
                [57461684, 54501256, 24368738, 538342.375, 328796.4063]]
        cols = ['Al', 'Si', 'Ca', 'Sc', 'Ti']

        data = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols, data=vals)
        data_list = data_p.to_numpy()
        data_max = data_list.max()
        data_min = data_list.min()

        p1 = gr_win.addPlot()
        il = pg.ImageItem(image=data_list)
        p1.addItem(il)
        p1.addColorBar(il, colorMap='CET-L9', values=(data_min,data_max))
        p1.setMouseEnabled(x=False, y=False)
        p1.disableAutoRange()
        p1.hideButtons()
        p1.showAxes(True, showValues=(True, False, False, True))


mkQApp('test')
main = MainWindow()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.exec()
```

A solution I imagine would be to split the matrix image in rows and set a minimum and a maximum value for each row in the same colorMap. But I was not able to find such function on pyqtgraph documentation.
Would anyone know how to solve it, or has another way to tackle the problem?